# Selecting all content of text input on focus doesn't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, microsoft-edge, textinput

I seem to have run into an Edge-specific problem with selecting all of the text in an input field.  I am using angular's ng-focus to call a function in the controller to select all the text in the field.

```js
function selectAllTextOnFocus($event) {
    $event.target.select();
}
```

This works fine in all browsers except Microsoft Edge, which will not select the text in the input field.

I have also tried another jQuery solution that works except for the first selection of the input field.  After that it works as intended and selects all of the text.

```js
$('input').on('focus', function (e) {
    $(this).one('mouseup', function () {
        $(this).select();
        return false;
    }).select();
});
```

Is this just a known issue with Microsoft Edge, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and see the issue to which you're referring. For the time being, you could call the *select* method after a brief delay:

```js
function selectAllTextOnFocus($event) {
    // See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8229660/
    if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge\/(13|14|15|16|17)/) ) {
        return setTimeout( $event.target.select.bind( $event.target ), 10)
    }
    $event.target.select();
}
```

Test both approaches here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xe9x9s7b/

I've taken the liberty to file [a public bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8229660/) on http://bugs.microsoftedge.com for tracking.

Comment: While this does work to fix the problem in edge it causes some unexpected behavior in chrome, when you have multiple input fields.  If you have a field selected and then click on another window and then select a different field when you click into chrome again it tries to select both fields contents.  Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uLdJu8yl1e0FOOz1yAUD?p=preview) that can reproduce the issue.  Thank you for the quick response, and for submitting the bug. I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: @SpencerMeyer Oh that is awesome  For now, you could use a bit of user-agent detection to avoid falling into this gap. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Since I don't like the solution, I did a jsfiddle, with `setSelectionRange` which works in every browser: https://jsfiddle.net/xe9x9s7b/11/

Also, you don't need 10ms as a timeout, 0 is fine, it just needs to get queued by the browser as far as I see

Comment: @Nicolas sadly, it is not a solution... we are talking about the "focus" event. see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xe9x9s7b/15/

Comment: Still an issue today in Edge/17.17134

Comment: The issue is still reproducible on Edge 18.17763 :(